# Solr Split string and storing into multiple fields while Indexing

Tags: solr

Right now I have a field that is getting indexed in the below format,

```
“my_field”:”Abc&Deo&Efg”
```

There can be "n" number of items separated by **"&"**, is there any way to split this field with **&** and store in separate field while Indexing in solr, field name can be the value itself in solr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do this in the update chain. Use a ScriptUpdateProcessor then write some Javascript to do this

```
<processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="script">updateProcessor.js</str>
</processor>
```

In update Processor script (in your conf directory):

```
    function processAdd(cmd) {
        doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
        field= doc.getFieldValue("my_field");

        // tokenize your string here on the & separate then put tokens into new field, which could be a multivalue
        doc.setField("mySplitField", token);
    }
```

The question is why you want to do this when you can simply tokenize on '&' when indexing then each component is searchable.

Here is some more info: https://dutchweballiance.nl/techblog/introducing-the-solr-scriptupdateprocessor/

Comment: Thanks, Ill definitely try your solution and let you know. Actually I want to store the values separated by "&" in different fields

Comment: That should be possible but you would either need to use dynamic fields eg: ampfield_* where the value is a count, say, or define all your fields in the schema in advance but I don't think you know the total number of fields.

Comment: How to config the update processor ? Let me edit my question and put up over there , you see than

Comment: Added a URL with some more information. Remember this has a small performance impact on updating.

Comment: How to pass the param to the script ?  <lst name="params">
        <str name="config_param">example config parameter</str>
    </lst> " headline_t" is my param

Comment: Good, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that with [Regular Expression Pattern Tokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer/)

I did a quick test by adding to schema.xml

```
    <field name="my_field" type="my_field_type" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <fieldType name="my_field_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="&amp;"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

So, basically the trick could be done with tokenizer, that will split data by some needed symbol, in your case it's ampersand.

[image]

Comment: thanks, will let you know ! anyways how to split and store it in different fields ?